# Snowflake Create View with JSON (VARIANT) field as columns with dynamic keys

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a problem creating VIEWS with Snowflake that has VARIANT field which stores JSON data whose keys are dynamic and keys definition is stored in another table. So I want to create a VIEW that has dynamic columns based on the foreign key.

Here are my table looks like:

companies:

```
| id | name      |
| -- | ----      |
| 1  | Company 1 |
| 2  | Company 2 |
```

invoices:

```
| id | invoice_number | custom_fields | company_id |
| -- | -------------- | ------------- | ---------- |
| 1  | INV-01         | {"1": "Joe", "3": true, "5": "2020-12-12"} | 1 |
| 2  | INV-01         | {"2":"Hello", "4": 1000} | 2 |
```

customization_fields:

```
| id | label     | data_type | company_id |
| -- | -----     | --------- | ---------- |
| 1  | manager   | text      | 1          |
| 2  | reference | text      | 2          |
| 3  | emailed   | boolean   | 1          |
| 4  | account   | integer   | 2          |
| 5  | due_date  | date      | 1          |
```

So I want to create a view for getting each companies invoices something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW companies_invoices AS SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE company_id = 1
```

which should get a result like below:

```
| id | invoice_number | company_id | manager | emailed | due_date   | 
| -- | -------------- | ---------- | ------- | ------- | --------   |
| 1  | INV-01         | 1          | Joe     | true    | 2020-12-12 |
```

So my challenge above here is I cannot make sure the keys when I write the query. If I know that I could write

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  invoice_number, 
  company_id, 
  custom_fields:"1" AS manager,  
  custom_fields:"3" AS emailed, 
  custom_fields:"5" AS due_date 
FROM invoices 
WHERE company_id = 1
```

These keys and labels are written in the `customization_fields` table, so I tried different ways and I am not able to do that.

So could anyone tell me if we can do or not? If we can please give me an example so it would really help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you want to do with a view.  A view has a fixed set of columns and they have specific types.  Retrieving a dynamic set of columns requires some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the number of columns or the names of the columns based on the rows in the customization_fields table, you can't do it in a view.

If you have a defined schema and just need to grab dynamic JSON properties, you may want to consider looking into Snowflake's GET function. It allows you to get any part of a JSON using a string for the path rather than using a literal path in the SQL statement. For example:

```
create temp table foo(v variant);
insert into foo select parse_json('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }');

-- This uses a literal path in the SQL to get to a JSON property
select v:name::string as first_name from foo;

-- This uses the GET function to get the value from a path in a string
select get(v, 'name')::string as first_name from foo;
```

You can replace the 'name' in the second parameter of the GET function with the value stored in the customization_fields table.

Answer (score 0):

In SF, You will have to use a Stored Proc function to retrieve the dynamic set of columns